# Nightwatch File Upload Validation

Tags: file-upload, nightwatch.js

I tried to compare the file upload to the data in database.
How to validate the file upload content to the data in database or User Interface in Nightwatch?

Comment: what is the issue you are facing? Your question doesn't show any code you have tried?

Comment: Show us the code you run when you try to compare the two. Are you looking at length, or timestamp, or sha224 hash of content?